# Xamarin.Android Click Button event is giving an exception, how can I fix it?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, events, button

When I try to run the emulator an Exception occurs on calculateButton.Click += delegate, I am trying to make a Tip Calculator so when the user click on the button the app start to compute.

The exception says
System.NullReferenceException has been thrown Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I tried numerous things

```
Button calculateButton;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   base.OnCreate(bundle);
   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
   calculateButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.calculateButton);
   calculateButton.Click += delegate
            {

                "insert calculations"
            };
        }
```

I also tried

```
Button calculateButton;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   base.OnCreate(bundle);
   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
   calculateButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.calculateButton);
   calculateButton.Click += OnCalculateClick;

   void OnCalculateClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                "insert calculations"
            };
        }
```

What I expect is when I click on the button the calculation will begin

Edit:
Here is activity_main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">

    </LinearLayout >

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is content_main.axml, I added the button here as the tutorial said to do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android        ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation  ="vertical"
    android:layout_width ="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:imeActionId="@+id/inputBill"
        android:layout_width ="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp" />

    <Button
        android:imeActionId="@+id/calculateButton"
        android:layout_width ="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text         ="CALCULATE"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.calculateButton);` is returning `null`, does calculateButton exist in activity_main?

Comment: @SushiHangover well I created that button on content_main.axml, the only code button related on activity_main is android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
which I removed from MainActivity because the tutorial told me to do so

Comment: you should add a Button which id is defined `calculateButton` in your `activity_main` axml,because current activity is Inflate from `Resource.Layout.activity_main`

Comment: there is probably some problem with that tutorial, or you are doing something wrong.  To run this code, your layout has to have `calculateButton` button in it, and you didn't show it for us to say if it has.

Comment: could it work now ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage is as follows

in your activity:

```
Button calculateButton;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

      // Create your application here
      SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
      calculateButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.calculateButton);
      calculateButton.Click += delegate
        {

            "insert calculations"
        };
  }
```

then in the **corresponding** axml(here is **activity_main**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <Button
     android:id="@+id/calculateButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
     android:text="Calculate"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I did that on content_main, I'm not sure how I can put it on activity_main, I edit my question to include both activity and content

Comment: you should use id button1

Comment: you should find your control by id which define with android:id